# How to remove punctuation inside brackets in R

Tags: r, brackets, punctuation

I have tried to split documents into sentences, but there are some strange outcomes due to punctuation inside brackets.  So I'd like to remove any punctuation.

example input:

```
A <- c('How to remove all punctuations(like this?) in side it?')
```

wanted output:

```
"How to remove all punctuations(like this) in side it?"
```

Comment: Note it's generally considered that there is [no need to add the language title into questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).  Also, there's no need to comment to thank people for a solution--but you should use the check mark to accept the answer (gives them points, and resolves the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this using a positive lookahead?

```
gsub("[?!;,.](?=\\))", "", A, perl = T)
#[1] "How to remove all punctuations(like this) in side it?"
```

Or using POSIX character classes

```
gsub("[[:punct:]](?=\\))", "", A, perl = T)
```

Or if you need to match other types of closing brackets (e.g. curly, square)

```
gsub("[[:punct:]](?=[)\\]}])", "", A, perl = T)
```